# use of "in" in mongodb

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, sql-in

I am using mongodb in vb.net

I need to send more than one resource_id similar to "in" in sql.

please help.

My Codes are:

```
Dim ConnString as String=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnStringMongo")
Dim server As MongoServer=MongoServer.Create(Connstring)
Dim ceilometer As MongoDatabase=server.GetDatabase("ceilometer")

Dim query=New QueryDocument()
query.Add("user_id","Jewel")
```

'' Is it possible? or how can i achieve this

```
 query.Add("resource_id","in('100','200')") 



Dim Docs=ceilometer.GetCollection("meter").Find(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
Dim resource_ids = New BsonValue() {"100", "200"}
Dim query = Query.And(
    Query.EQ("user_id", "Jewel"),
    Query.In("resource_id", resource_ids)
)

Dim Docs = ceilometer.GetCollection("meter").Find(query)
```

Comment: then how can i get collection by this query?                                                              Dim Docs=ceilometer.GetCollection("meter").Find(query)

Comment: one thing, resource_ids from my side is dynamic and i am suffering here adding double quote, please help

Comment: Your other issue is not clear, can you please create a new question outlining the problem you are having and include an example if you can.

Comment: chridam, here's my another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352053/use-of-double-quotes-as-string

Comment: Ok, let me have a look at it in a bit and will try to help you solve it.