# use of double quotes as string

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I am developing in vb.net

```
Dim dtDetails As DataTable = Utility.GetDetailsTable()
Dim resource_id As String = ""

Dim dtrow = dtDetails.Select("id='" & user_id & "'")
If dtrow.Length > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To dtrow.Length - 1
       If i > 0 Then
          resource_id += ","
       End If
       resource_id += Convert.ToString(dtrow(i)("instance_id"))
    Next
```

but when I use resource_id further, it is not working, Docs returns as empty

```
Dim resource_ids = New BsonValue() {resource_id}
Dim querys = Query.And(
    Query.EQ("user_id", user_id),
    Query.In("resource_id", resource_ids)
)

Dim Docs = ceilometer.GetCollection("meter").Find(querys)
```

because I need it in this format `BsonValue(){"resource_id1","resource_id2"}`. Please help me to solve this

Comment: [this might be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24145158/1070452) hard to tell from the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From how I understood your question, I believe you need to add the dynamic ids to the `BsonValue` array. Using an extension from this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18267830/):

```
<Extension()> _
Public Sub Add(Of T)(ByRef arr As T(), item As T)
    Array.Resize(arr, arr.Length + 1)
    arr(arr.Length - 1) = item
End Sub
```

Which you can then use in your code as:

```
Dim dtDetails As DataTable = Utility.GetDetailsTable()
Dim resource_ids As new BsonArray

Dim dtrow = dtDetails.Select("id='" & user_id & "'")
If dtrow.Length > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To dtrow.Length - 1
       resource_ids.Add(Convert.ToString(dtrow(i)("instance_id")))
    Next
End If

Dim queries = Query.And(
    Query.EQ("user_id", user_id),
    Query.In("resource_id", resource_ids)
)

Dim Docs = ceilometer.GetCollection("meter").Find(queries)
```

Comment: It shows error "add is not a member of system.array"   in resource_ids.Add(Convert.ToString(dtrow(i)("instance_id")))

Comment: Did you add the extension?

Comment: which extension? I add MongoDB.Bson, Driver, Driver.Builders

Comment: it works if I replace Dim resource_ids As new BsonArray, Please edit the answer so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: another query is i want to add sql like operator such as resource_ids like "%chridam%" or resource_ids like "%zaman%", please help

Comment: Hi @SyedMd.Kamruzzaman, I have edited the answer to include the working part, thanks for taking note. About the other issue, once again I would encourage you to open/create a new question, that way you can get wider help from the community or better answers as I may not be able to be of help always.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, as an expert MongoDb user, if possible, help me otherwise I will seek. Thanks a lot again for answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74174/discussion-between-syed-md-kamruzzaman-and-chridam).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't enable chat at the moment due to my internet policy. Let me know when you have created the new question and I will try my best to help.

Comment: thanks. questions link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364100/use-of-like-operator-in-mongodb